# One way to do in-process dynamic plugin in golang

Tags: go, plugins, dynamic-loading

recently I'm trying to build a dynamic plugin framework in golang, I know the `plugin` buildmode hasn't been implemented yet.

So I'm thinking about building go plugin into c-style shared objects and the main program loading plugins using `C.dlopen`.

Complex data struct can be passed by json-encoded string.

Is this means doable?  Or is there any foreseeable disadvantage could be caused?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about writing plugins in Lua? https://github.com/Shopify/go-lua

Comment: buildmode=plugin will be supported from Go 1.8+ onwards. See the release notes here: https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.8

Comment: @DuruCanCelasun But I can't find any release schedule of Go1.8, when will it release?

Comment: It will be released in early February, when the open issues are closed: https://github.com/golang/go/milestone/38

Comment: If you want plugins written in Go, there's a reason no one has made plugins via `buildmode=c-shared`; you can't really do that since the shared library is meant to be a full Go runtime loadable by another non-go program. If you want an immediate and stable option, there's numerous projects using rpc-based plugin systems,  for example: [github.com/hashicorp/go-plugin/](https://github.com/hashicorp/go-plugin/)

Comment: Additional way is using [jsonrpc](https://golang.org/pkg/net/rpc/jsonrpc/) or [gRPC](http://www.grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/go.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method is not a possible way to do the dynamic plugin loading/reloading. 
The detail lies here: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/11100

Even the plugin feature in golang 1.8 doesn't support reloading.